# how to clean an useMutation error if is a constant?

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

If you have the following code in the functional component with React hooks, how to clean a useMutation error if is a constant?

```
const [addItemToDB, { error }] = useMutation(addItemMutation);
  if (error) {
    console.log("error:", error);
    return <p>Error :(</p>;
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by cleaning it?

Comment: Since is a constant it persists, so the the component need to be unmounted, right?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use it as part of a component, then the `const` will be evaluated again on the next render. As such, it will not persist in-between login attempts and thus there's no need to clean it.

E.g. I use it like this and even if the user gets an error the first time they log in, it still allows them to try again and succeed:

```js
const LoginPage: = ({doLogin}: LoginProps) => {
    const [login, { loading, error }] = useMutation<LoginResponse, LoginVariables>(
        LOGIN_MUTATION, { onCompleted: (response: LoginResponse) => doLogin(response) }
    )

  return <>
    // Render my login component
  </>
}
```

If your intent is to overwrite the error value in the current render, then you can just assign a new variable and use that instead:

```js
const [login, { error }] = useMutation<...>(...)

const overwrittenError = customizedErrorMessage(error)
const potentiallyIgnoredError = shouldErrorBeIgnored(error) && error

return <>
  <>Custom error: { overwrittenError }</>
  <>This error might be ignored: { potentiallyIgnoredError }</>
  <>Original error: { error }</>
</>
```